# Pick wwwroot/_content/ files from 3rd party Blazor library when publishing

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, blazor, .net-5

I have an ASP.NET core 5 project that references some 3rd party Blazor libraries.

When I publish the project, it includes a lot of static asset files in `$publishDir/wwwroot/_content/LiraryName/` folder, which is slowing down deployment. I don't need them all.

Is it possible to configure, which files should be skipped while publishing?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the files with a post-build script?

Comment: No, I hope I can prevent it from being published by editing csproj

Comment: Maybe the use  ```      
 <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>wwwroot/_content/LiraryName/;wwwroot/_content/LiraryName2/</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment> 
        <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>wwwroot/_content/LiraryName/file1.js</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>

in the publish profile XML (.pubxml) of the host project. could help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way:

Just use these:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    
    <Content Update="wwwroot\_content\LiraryName\*.*">   
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>

  </ItemGroup>
```

Before using it, please first delete the **publish** folder.

================

**Update 1**

**Solution One**

**1)** add  `GeneratePathProperty="true"` into the nuget package reference node to generate the msbuild property `PkgBlazored_Toast` to access the content of the nuget package like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.Toast" Version="3.1.2" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**2)** add this:

```
 <Target Name="RemoveTheFiles"  AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">-->
  <ItemGroup> 
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Remove="$(PkgBlazored_Toast)\staticwebassets\*.*"></ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

**Also**, first,delete the previous **publish** folder and then run the publish.

**Solution Two**

**1)** use `Delete` Task:

```
<Target Name="RemoveTheFiles" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Folder>$(PublishUrl)wwwroot\_content</Folder>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(Folder)"></RemoveDir>
 </Target>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I have tried Blazored.Toast package reference and  `<Content Update="wwwroot\_content\**\*.*">`, but it's published. Is it because those files are from different assembly and editing my .csproj does affect those?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the nuget package and that is the key. Since the files are imported by the nuget package by its own rule and the files are not contained into the solution explorer, the first suggestion(works for the content on the solution explorer) does not work for it. I recommend you use another way. See my `update 1`.

Comment: Update 1, solution one does not work (at least in .NET 6). Static web assets are not included in ResolvedFileToPublish

Answer (score -4):

I have my NPM folder --> NpmJS inside wwwroot
Edit the csproj file like this:
Works like a charm.

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="wwwroot\NpmJS" />
  <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="wwwroot\NpmJS" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your own post.  If you want to delete it, delete it.  Even after deleted, _some_ users (with the earned privilege) will be able to see it.